# Troubleshooting for Power Delivery with Shunt Capacitor

Tags: power, shunt, apparent-power

I have been trying to derive an equation to find the power delivered to R(load) for the following circuit[image]

In order to do so I used voltage division

[image]

Which simplified equated tp

[image]

Then using the fact that

[image]

I arrived at

[image]

But when calculating for values such as

[image]

I get

[image]

Which is very different than what I got experimentally, and (I could be very wrong here) wouldn't it imply

[image]

Which would not be possible due to it being greater than the magnitude of the input voltage.

If there's anyway someone could help me out with this I would be very grateful. What started out as a simple lab experiment has become a rabbit hole taking all my attention away from finals hahaha. I have all the derivations written on paper and I think there's no point in uploading them as I checked everything I arrived at with Wolfram to make sure it was algebraically sound. Nevertheless I could upload them if requested. I have also just stumbled upon this forum so I am sorry if I am breaking some rules or posting in the wrong place. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is not "omega =5 kHz" but f=5 kHz.
omega = 5000 rad/s -> \$f= 5000/(2*pi)\$ = 795 Hz ...

And yes, output is greater than input at this frequency, quasi 8 Vpeak.
[image]